# Calculations between 2 records of 2 tables need to extend to more then 1300 fields. How and which database can achieve this?

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design

For one of our projects we are using PostgreSQL and access two tables with complex SQL calculations due to performance advantages.

Each table, lets call them `TableA` and `TableB`, have 1301 fields of type double precision (field number restriction by PostgreSQL!) The field names for `TableA` are: `id`, `A1`, `A2`, ..., `A1300` and for `TableB`: `id`, `B2`, ..., `B1300`.

We are using many dynamically changing formulas which can directly access the two tables with a simple `id` join to do calculations over the numeric data in the records.

An example formula would be: `A99 * ((A1 * B3) / (B5 * B88))`

So the program can simply take the formula and directly use it in its SQL like:

```
select A99 * ((A1 * B3) / (B5 * B88)) as ResultValue
from TableA A
join TableB B on A.id = B.id
```

This worked fast in one DB request to 2 indexed tables.
But over time, the system has grown, and all the available fields are used up.

Now, the requirement is to have nearly no restriction in the amount of used fields, to accommodate much longer and more complex calculations in one SQL `select` over 2 tables.
I must admit I don't know much about many other new database systems and their capabilities for such a problem. Are there databases which would support such a concept or another way to have those calculations done in the database?
The old way was very flexible for the time being, but is there a more efficient way to implement the same logic?
Reading out the data dynamically in to the program, parsing it and calculating with it will probably take much longer.
I also think just using another database which allows defining tables with more then 1300 fields would be a short term solution, until we need more fields.

Comment: Out of curiousity, If the values are all doubles, why not use an array instead?

Comment: That sounds like an interesting solution and would lift the restriction of the field length. I have to admit that I never used the datatype array before...
I assume the space for the array is allocated dynamically so I could theoretically adjust it depending on the actual project.
I will try to use it and also see if there is a performance problem.
I just would need to change a couple of millions of formula but for that I might just write a parser to run a couple of days :-)

Comment: Array datatypes in Pg are fantastic.  I wish more DBMS platforms supported them.  As far as I know, they are dynamic.  I change the contents on the fly and have never had to bother myself with bounds.  Referencing an out of bounds value will simply return a null.  With regards to your parsing problem -- sounds like a job for a regular expression...  Perl could probably do 99% of the heavy lifting on that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an example to my comment above, using an array rather than discrete fields for each value:

```
create table tablea (
  id int not null,
  a numeric[]
);    

create table tableb (
  id int not null,
  b numeric[]
);

insert into tablea
select 2, array (select generate_series(1,10000));

insert into tableb
select 2, array (select generate_series(1,10000));


select
  A[99] * ((A[1] * B[3]) / (B[5] * B[88])) 
from
  tablea
  join tableb on
    tablea.id = tableb.id
where
  tablea.id = 2;
```